# Are you allowed to "spill the seed" when your wife is pregnant, post-menopausal, or otherwise infertile?

Tags: halacha, marriage

I'm assuming you are not allowed to, but why not? Or is it not even possible to do so if your partner is infertile?

Comment: Why aren't you getting yourself a fertile wife?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/90142/170

Comment: It's unstated but I believe the premise of the question is that if relations are permitted with these women, who can't become pregnant through this act of intimacy, this should be considered spilling seed (it's not). The (correct) assumption is that there's no prohibition here, so the (incorrect) extrapolation is that all spilling seed should be permitted. The questioner knows that's not the case, and wants to know why.

Comment: @robev rephrased my (apparently unpopular) question for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed to have relations with an infertile wife? Absolutely  yes. Is that your question? Please edit for clarity. In general, longer questions will get higher ratings.

Answer (score 1):

Halacha does not seem to make exceptions for the cases you mention or any other case.

> As Rabbi Yoḥanan says: Anyone who emits semen for naught deserves death [at the hand of Heaven]. [Niddah 13a]

And the code of Jewish law formalizes it [SA, Even HaEzer 23:1-3]:

> It is prohibited to spill seed needlessly and this sin is more severe than all Torah transgressions. For this reason a man should not thresh inside and sprinkle [his semen] outside [of a woman], and he should not marry a girl who is unable to have children.

> Those who 'commit adultery' with their hand and thereby cause semen to be spilled it is not enough that this is a great prohibition, but one who does so should sit in excommunication and about them it is said "Their hands are full of blood" and it is as if they have killed a person.

> It is forbidden for a man intentionally make himself have an erection or to cause himself to think about sex. Rather if he thinks about sex he should remove himself from vain things and go to the words of Torah which is like a beloved doe and a graceful deer.

Comment: If I'm correct about the premise of the question, perhaps address as well the points I raised.

Comment: It appears you have misunderstood the question. The OP wants to know if relations in those cases is considered wasting seed.

Comment: He asked why.  I don't think the Sources go into that.  They just say no.

Comment: Rema clearly permits marrying an infertile wife. I assume you’re Sephardi.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%9B%D7%93

Comment: @LN6595 Where? I only remember him saying we don't protest such a violator.